# android - sliding menu start Activity on Item Click

Tags: android

In my App i implemented the **SlidingMenu Library** by **jfeinstein10**. 
Everything works fine (official example app) but i dont know how to set an action to an item on the list (slide menu).
I want to start another Activity on item click.
Can someone give me a little example how to do that please ?

Comment: Do you want to start activity on item click of sliding menu list??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood, you want to start activity on item click of the menu.

So write item click listener for sliding menu :

```
list.setOnItemClickListener( new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        Intent intent =  new Intent(this,next_activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    });
}
```

Comment: and how i do that for more than 1 items in the list ?

Comment: This method will be called for each and every item of the list

Comment: ma pleasure.. :) if it is helpful, make it accepted so that other people get right answer :)